# svg filter is hidiing other elements on zoom or drag

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a d3.js tree which will be generated dynamically. I am allowing user to drag on each node and drag and zoom on the entire pane. On click of each node I am highlighting the node and the paths connected to that node.

```
<filter id="yellow-glow" x="-500" y="-500" width="1000" height="1000" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<feFlood result="flood" flood-color="yellow" flodd-opacity="1"/>  
<feComposite in="flood" result="mask" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"/>
<feMorphology in="mask" result="dilated" operator="dilate" radius="2"/>
<feGaussianBlur in="dilated" result="blurred" stdDeviation="5"/>
<feMerge><feMergeNode in="blurred"/>
<feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/></feMerge>
```

This is my filter element. Problem is with the attributes of filter tag. If I give x= -5000,y=-5000,width=10000,height = 10000 it works fine in chrome but firefox hides the element when filter overflows screen resolution. If I give values according to screen resolution when tree is bigger than screen size filter is breaking in middle.

What should be the dimensions for filter tag ?

Comment: Use a different method of highlighting e.g. change the colour or opacity of the elements.

Comment: user wants it this way

Comment: Its not changing the color it keeps the same color but gives an yellow over glow https://jsfiddle.net/nq6bb581/2/

Comment: Make the filter an objectBoundingBox filter and apply it to each element separately.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it using the same filter but changing the x,y values. width and height I am giving same as screen width and screen height